# Не получается отправить изображение в бд

Tags: python, mysql, opencv

Есть скрипт, который делает раз в 120 секунд фото с камеры. Мне необходимо это изображение загрузить в бд, чтобы в дальнейшем его вывести на сайте.

Код скрипта:

```
    import numpy as np
import cv2
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
from python_mysql_dbconfig import read_db_config
from time import sleep
import serial
import time

try:
    db_config = read_db_config()
    conn = MySQLConnection(**db_config)

    cursor = conn.cursor()

    conn.commit()
except Error as error:
    print(error)

cursor = conn.cursor()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Check if the webcam is opened correctly
if not cap.isOpened():
    raise IOError("Cannot open webcam")

frame = cap.read()[1]
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO images (photo) VALUES %s", (frame,))
cap.release()

time.sleep(120)
```

При запуске вываливается следующая ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    "Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % err)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'ndarray' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
[ WARN:0] terminating async callback
```

Насколько я понял, изображение представляет собой массив, который mysql не может принять. Я пробовал использовать "bytes" для преобразования фрейма в двоичную строку, но ничего не получилось. Как решить проблему?

Comment: Из текста сообщения ясно, что ваша переменная *frame* имеет тип *ndarray*. Что это такое - Вам виднее.  А вот какой тип имеет колонка *photo* в таблице *images* ? В зависимости от этого надо выполнять соответствующее преобразование.

Comment: В таблице колонка photo имеет тип medium bloob. У меня картинка сохраняется на одноплатнике. Может есть смысл уже брать её (она в формате .png) и грузить в бд?

Comment: *тип medium bloob* понятно, что в pyttone нет такого типа среди стандартных.  Я думаю, что надо посмотреть  руководство по питоновскому модулю для MySQL и найти, какой тип данных соответствует блобам. Скорее всего - байтовый массив. Для преобразования произвольных данных питона в байтовый массив есть модуль *struct*, а в нём метод  *pack*. Попробуйте сначала упаковать Ваш *frame*, а уже потом - преобразовать с помощью *bytes()*.